# Hi everyone.. I am new to all this.. I am having trouble installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

My first question was downvoted due to how messy my question was.. i will do my best to explain my situation clearly :)

So I own some LAND in decentraland (a crypto vr world) and i want to start building on it.. There is a installation guide and the first line is (`npm install -g decentraland`)

When i ran this prompt i got an error message.. after googling around i found this - https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

So i followed the instructions for the second fix.. but stupidly i just went in all guns blazing and i think i made it worst.. I now get this error message -

> users-MacBook-Pro:desktop user$ npm install -g decentraland
> npm ERR! Error while executing:
> npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/dignifiedquire/webcrypto-shim.git
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! exited with error code: 1
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-09-26T16_16_38_709Z-debug.log

I have very little idea what i'm doing but i think once i have it installed i will be able to follow the installation guide..

Comment: I've reformatted your error as a blockquote. The magic trick is to force newlines by putting a double space at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on a Mac, the easiest way to get what you want is to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and install node + npm through brew. Plenty of tutorials online, but here is the gist:

**Download and install homebrew**:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Download and install node and npm**

```
$ brew install node
```

Comment: When i type the first prompt i get - users-MacBook-Pro:desktop user$ $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
-bash: $: command not found

Comment: haha yea, the "dollar sign" represents in the terminal where your command begins. Notice how, in your case, `users-MacBook-Pro:desktop user$` is terminated with a `$`? Just omit the dollar sign in my answer and it will run

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/).
2. Use sudo to install global NPMs (`sudo npm install -g decentraland`).